# Language PHP array - elegant way to pass to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, escaping, translation

I have a database with strings and which language this string belongs. A string has a unique name, which I use to identify it, and then a translation for each language.

With PHP, I get this information from the database and store it in an associative array like:

```
$languages['strings']['lang']['unique_string_name'] = $translation;
```

Now, as I want my Javascript code to be translated too, I need to pass it to. I've tried doing it in JSON, but some $translation have quotes and double quotes, and it's a hell to escape and get it all correct - because escaping just escapes the whole JSON string, not only translation.

So, what I've done is loop the whole array and echoing the $translation in a Javascript associative array again, but this time with addslashes - only the translation.

However, if I look to the Source Code, I see 600 lines of Javascripts entries, one for each translation (of course, this has nothing strange, just simply UGLY).

I was wondering if there's a much cleaner way of passing this translation array to my Javascript code without having to loop the PHP array and echo it to a JS variable.

Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: How did you do the JSON? Did you use the actual PHP and Javascript functions for that? `$str = json_encode($languages);` for PHP and `var languages = JSON.parse(str);` for Javascript should work.

Comment: `var languages = <?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>;` - Done.

Comment: http://php.net/json_encode is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var languages = <?php echo json_encode($languages); ?>;
</script>
```

You'll end up with an exact duplicate of your PHP array in JS, so

```
echo $languages['strings']['lang']['unique_string_name']; // PHP
alert(languages.strings.lang.unique_string_name); // JS
```

will both bring up the same translation.

Comment: Hello Marc! Thanks for your answer, but as I told in the question, I've got some strings with single quotes and double quotes. Doing it this way ended up with an "Unexpected identifier X". As the names/identifiers of the JSON array start are between "" (double quotes), JSON does not accept any of its values double quoted without scaping. If I scape the whole JSON array, I ended up with the same type of error.

Comment: that's why you use json_encode. it'll translate EVERYTHING in the passed-in data structure to valid javascsript, including escaping any necessary JS metacharacters. If you mean that some of your array KEYS have quotes, then you'd use `var['key with \' quote']` type notation when accessing the array. JSON will only handle the PHP->javascript transition. It'll be up to you to write appropriate JS code to handle the data structure.

Comment: You're so right. I don't know what I made before, as I was getting always an error. Of course, something wrong was being made by my part :P Thanks for your time and sorry for my noob question! I don't know what happened to get the errors I got! Thanks again. Marked the question as accepted.